# image on load in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

im using something like

```
        #need to load an image
        newImage = new Image()
        newImage.onload ->
            console.log("image loaded")
        newImage.src = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
```

which compiles to

```
    newImage.onload(function() {
      return console.log("image loaded");
    });
```

which is not what I need, how do i call a function on load ?

Comment: because of optionally omitted parens `blah -> foo` just calls `blah` with the first arg being an anonymous function returning `foo`. Use `=` to assign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
newImage.onload = ->
     console.log("image loaded")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
newImage.on('load', console.log("image loaded"))
```

Answer (score 0):

to add a little complexity
to allow to do more complext functions inside the onload, you can use this to refer to the object

```
newImage.onload= doThisNow 

doThisNow=->
image=this
console.log 'image ' + image.id + ' loaded'
```